# Product view is blank on certain products

Tags: magento-1.9, error, product-view

The product view page is blank on some products within my Magento store. I have the following error in the log:

```
[05-Oct-2015 21:18:34 UTC] PHP Fatal error: `Call to a member function productAttribute() on a non-object in /home/mysite/public_html/app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 69`
```

The piece of code to which this refers is as follows:

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

Can anyone please assist with this issue?

All products on the site are imported via database. As far as I can see the only difference with the products that appear blank is that there's no '`short description`' content. I've added content to the short description as a test but that didn't seem to fix the issue. Short description is identified as a required field.

Comment: I am getting the same issue, how can I find what is the issue? There is no console error and log error even view page source also empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***May be helper class is  not called here.***

**So you   need to call helper class .please add below code before your code**

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output'); ?>
```

Comment: "Product view is blank on certain products" not for all product. if that line is not present all page goes blank

Comment: So <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output'); ?> <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?> Amit?

Comment: yes..  you have going to right direction

Comment: @AmitBera which file i need to add the above code?